# Creating a stream from a text file in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm getting the following error when I try to create a stream from a text file in Pyspark:

`TypeError: unbound method textFileStream() must be called with StreamingContext instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`

I don't want to use `SparkContext` because I get another error so to remove thet error I have to use `SparkSession`.

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics
if __name__ == "__main__":

   spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CrossCorrelation").getOrCreate()
   ssc = StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, 5)
   input_path1 = sys.argv[1]
   input_path2 = sys.argv[2]
   ds1 = ssc.textFileStream(input_path1)
   lines1 = ds1.map(lambda x1: x1[1])
   windowedds1 = lines1.flatMap(lambda line1: line1.strip().split("\n")).map(lambda strelem1: float(strelem1)).window(5,10)
   ds2 = ssc.textFileStream(input_path2)
   lines2 = ds2.map(lambda x2: x2[1])
   windowedds2 = lines2.flatMap(lambda line2: line2.strip().split("\n")).map(lambda strelem2: float(strelem2)).window(5,10)







   result = Statistics.corr(windowedds1,windowedds2, method="pearson")
   if result > 0.7:
    print("ds1 and ds2 are correlated!!!")


   spark.stop()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create streamingcontext object and then use it to call textFileStream.

```
spark = 
SparkSession.builder.appName("CrossCorrelation").getOrCreate()
ssc = StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, 1)
ds = ssc.textFileStream(input_path)
```

Comment: I can't use SparkContext because in that case I get the following error:
`It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transforamtion` . So I have to use SparkSession only.

Comment: in that case, you can sparkContext from sparkSession , you can use it while creating StreamingContext.Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you but I get the same error as I use SparkConext:
`Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.` The error comes from this line : `result = Statistics.corr(windowedds1,windowedds2, method="pearson")` where I calculate the correlation between two windows of streams. See the updated code above. Thanks!

Comment: may be you can create streamingcontext using conf  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))

Comment: Thanks! But that may work for scala. I'm using Pyspark and in Pyspark I tried creating SparkConf and passed it to StreamingContext but I got an error.